# C# Linq - Find Conflicting Times

Tags: c#, linq

I thought this would be pretty straight forward, but I'm having  'brain fog'

Scenario:
The customer wants to book there next appointment(s), 10-Dec-2020 16:00 (start) to 10-Dec-2020 17:00 (end)

The member of staff needs to work out if they have that time free?
(The next appointment-free would be 17:00 - 18:00)

I want to be able to:
Work out if this time is free (ie no other appointments that fall within this range), however, I also need to keep in mind that if an appointment ends at 17:00 and the next appointment could start from 17:00 to 18:00 that this does not come back as unavailable?

This is what I have done so far, but I keep getting incorrect results back?

```
 public IEnumerable<DomainObjects.Event> FindAllEventsByUserId(string userId, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            var appointments =
                RepositorySet
                    .Where(c => c.ResourceId == userId && !c.IsDeleted &&
                                (
                                    (c.StartTime >= startTime && c.StartTime <= endTime) ||
                                    (c.EndTime >= startTime && c.EndTime <= endTime) ||
                                    (c.StartTime <= startTime && c.EndTime >= endTime))
                    ).AsEnumerable();
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a check that two intervals overlap, similarly as in 1D lines. However, overlap in an endpoint is not acceptable, so we need to specialize a bit.

Let's abstract this just to two intervals of AB and CD where A and C represent starts and B and D represent ends.

When do intervals overlap? Either:

1. A <= C and B >= D (AB is superset (or equal) of CD)
   [image]
2. A >= C and A < D (A lies within CD, start inclusive)
   [image]
3. B > C and B <= D (B lies within CD, end inclusive)
   [image]

Note that case of AB being subset of CD is combination of #2 and #3.

Therefore: (A <= C && B >= D) || (A >= C && A < D) || (B > C && B <= D)

In C#:

```
var overlap = (c.StartTime <= startTime && c.EndTime >= endTime)
    || (c.StartTime >= startTime && c.StartTime < endTime)
    || (c.EndTime > startTime && c.EndTime <= endTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If one startTime is before the others endTime, and that endTime is after the others startTime then there is overlap.

If you want to return conflicting entries within the time period that leaves you with:

```
public IEnumerable<DomainObjects.Event> FindAllEventsByUserId(string userId, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var appointments =
        RepositorySet
            .Where(c => c.ResourceId == userId && !c.IsDeleted &&
                c.StartTime < endTime && c.EndTime > startTime
            ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

Proof:

```
var time1start = new DateTime(2020, 12, 10, 16, 0, 0);
var time1end = new DateTime(2020, 12, 10, 17, 0, 0);

var time2start = new DateTime(2020, 12, 10, 17, 0, 0);
var time2end = new DateTime(2020, 12, 10, 18, 0, 0);

var time3start = new DateTime(2020, 12, 10, 16, 30, 0);
var time3end = new DateTime(2020, 12, 10, 17, 30, 0);

Console.WriteLine(time1start < time2end && time1end > time2start); // false (correct)
Console.WriteLine(time1start < time3end && time1end > time3start); // true (corrent)
Console.WriteLine(time1start <= time2end && time1end >= time2start); // true (wrong)
```

Comment: I agree, only it should be '<=' and '>=' accordingly (since a meeting can start at 17:00 even if a previous meeting ended at that same time).

Comment: No, I just tested it and if you use `<=` and `>=` then an appointment that ends at say 11:00 would match one that starts at 11:00, which is not what is wanted

Comment: I've added proof to the answer